# What templating engine to use for expressjs 4.x?

Tags: node.js, express, templating

I don't want to use jade as i can't keep track of spaces and what is under what.

I wanted to use something simple like hogan. But default one doesn't have what i want and alternative support express 3.x.

I want minimum of these features:

- Ability to include/import static layout from other templates. So i can type {{>navigation}} and also ability to concat templates together.
- Ability to precompile, so static files and files that do not change often, once a day, are compiled and cached etc.
- Some ability for repetition, so i can do for keys in object repeat this element with this data.

what do you think is jad the only option, does jade support all of it.

Comment: also i read somewhere that in certain templating engines you have to pre declare partials. Which is  inconvenient..

Comment: Besides hogan, what else have you researched?

Comment: mustache, handlebar, dotjs, ejs. mustache and handlebar i think don't have layout and precompile option in nodejss.

Comment: what about ejs? I like the linkedin version of dust, but I'm not sure if it meets all your needs.

Comment: actually in dust it looks like you can precompile, assuming we are talking about the same thing. Heres a link to the guide: http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/#guide

Comment: i was trying to stay close to original html. (the reason jade doesn't look good to me). I want to stay close to html is because it's easier to troubleshoot, and understand.

Comment: Is EJS not close to the orginal html? Same for dust. I would imagine you will have to accept some templating syntax mixed in with your markup no matter what solution you choose.

Comment: ejs looks ok, even though i dont like that..but still i will accept it. However, where are the documentation. The site looks abandoned. How do i include raw html file.

Comment: i'd use even jade if there was sublimetext plugin to convert all html to jade. So i'd do the whole site in html and when i am satisfied with it ill just press key and it'd be jade. I can understand jade. It's just i don't like to debug it or handle complicated attributes in it.

Comment: @RayStantz im thinking of for now to stick with jade and use this site http://html2jade.org/